# Mongo ObjectID stored as object instead of ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, message-queue, publish-subscribe, objectid

I'm currently building a pubsub message queue using mongo's capped collections and tailable cursors (along the lines of [this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pub-sub-with-mongodb) and [this](https://blog.serverdensity.com/replacing-rabbitmq-with-mongodb/)).

I'm using mongo and node.js on OS X Yosemite.

When I save, occasionally the object id gets stored as an object. The object id is created by mongo. Not by node. This is what it looks like in robomongo.

[image]

I've tried different combinations of keywords to see if any one else has dealt with this problem, and so far nothing. I should mention that I have multiple services connected to the same database, inserting/updating. Are there any common reasons why mongo would do this.